# Can't redirect using res.redirect(), express + NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I am building my first app in Node.js. Everything was going fine until now. I am facing a problem while trying to redirect using server-side code in Node.js application doesn't throw any error, but on the browser it stays on the same page and doesn't redirect to chatroom page from the index page.

Index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var obj = require('../bin/www');
var db = require('../databaseModels');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('index', { title: 'Express Chat' });
});

//here we will save the username of the New user
router.post("/setUserName", async function(req,res) {
try{
    var newUser = new db.Users(req.body);
    await newUser.save()
    //Emit the event that a new user has joined the chat
    obj.io.emit("newUserJoined", req.body)
    return res.redirect(301,"http://192.168.34.54:4747/chatroom");
}
catch(error) {
    res.sendStatus(500);
    console.log(error);
}
})

module.exports = router;
```

chatroom.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var obj = require('../bin/www');
var db = require('../databaseModels');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('chatroom', {title: 'Welcome to Chat Room'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing ?
and have you tried to remove your ip ?
only put `/chatroom`

Comment: Problem is when i call setUserName method form index page on a button click it save the username in DataBase but it doesn't redirect to chatroom page. No i didn't tried that way @BasilBattikhi

Comment: Are you calling `POST /setUserName` using AJAX/XMLHttpRequest/fetch?

Comment: $.post('url') method. but i tried with $.get('ulr') also. still not working @robertklep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your 'chatroom' router in bin/www like you have used 'index' router.

```
app.use('/chatroom',chatroom);
```

and in index router, use relative paths while calling the chatroom router.

```
return res.redirect(301,"/chatroom");
```

Comment: i already done this 

`app.use('/', indexRouter);`

`app.use('/chatroom', chatroomRouter);`

added these lines in app.js

still not working

Comment: i am not getting any error.
debugger prints this.
'GET /setUserName/gjnhgjhjjytjy 301 8.911 ms - 43'
'GET /chatroom 304 4.263 ms - -'

Comment: If you are using jQuery , then don't redirect from the API.

Comment: Just pass {success : true/false} from the /index and through jQuery, redirect to /dashboard when you get success: true.

Comment: i think i found the reason thanks to  @Ratish. i am using $.post() method so i think i have to send the url in response and redirect it from the front end right?

Comment: ok thank you true or false will also work.

Comment: Window.location.replace('http://<host>:<port>/dashboard')

Comment: Yes this will work. Cheers!

Comment: thank you for saving the day :)